# hidden facebook like button not displayed with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook

I inserted a facebook like button code in a div with class=social which is hidden with csss

```
    <div class="social">
      ///facebook like button code here
    </div>
```

so at some point in time i show the div with jquery fadeIn()
everything works fine on chrome, but on firefox the facebook like button is hidden.

Comment: without sharing your html and JavaScript, there is no way we can answer this question by looking at a div tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is: does it work if you don´t hide it initially? Else you could try to parse it again after making it visible:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

But normally, this should be no problem, as long as you don´t load it dynamically.